# Error when setting up a custom error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Good time of day. For the custom error page, the setting is specified in web.config:

```xml
<system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On">
          <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

However, if an error occurs in the application, a 404 page opens indicating that the specified "Views/Shared/Error.aspx" page does not exist, although this is not the case. Perhaps the path for the Shared folder needs to be specified in some other way?